# mod rewrite recursion error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file that redirects requests to a php API using the directive below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

The RewriteRule seems to be causing a redirect recursive error. I have the exact same directive and API running on another Apache server with the same hosting company with no issues at all in production. Both sites run from out of a subdomain, each on a seperate shared hosting account.

Folder structure is the same on both shared hosts:

```
├── root
│   ├── subdom
│   │   ├── .htaccess
│   │   ├── api
│   │   │    ├── v1
│   │   │    │   ├── index.php (API entry point)
```

Here is the error that is caught in the error log, no error gets caught by the index.php in the API.

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I've compared phpinfo outputs, all the settings and versions are the same.

Tests:

This method fails on one of the shared hosting accounts

```
subdom.domain.com/api/v1/endpoint/arg
```

This method works on both shared hosting accounts

```
domain.com/subdom/api/v1/endpoint/arg
```

This method hits the api without errors on both hosting accounts

```
subdom.domain.com/api/v1/
```

Comment: check the contents of the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Or to change (with `/`):

```
RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ /api/v1/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: It is working with no errors now. I ended up adding a forward slash here: /api/v1/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]